# Get Serial Number of Boot Drive and other info

Tags: c#, hardware

I am trying to get the serial number of the boot drive and I haven't figured out how to do it.

I do understand that the partition =\= hard drive but I'd like the serial of the boot partition.

This what I have so far:

```
        var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");

        int i = 0;
        foreach (ManagementObject wmi_HD in searcher.Get())
        {
            // get the hardware serial no.
            if (wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] == null)
                richTextBox1.Text += "None" + Environment.NewLine;
            else
                richTextBox1.Text += "Name: " + wmi_HD["Name"] + Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.Text += "SerialNumber: " + wmi_HD["SerialNumber"] + Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.Text += "MediaType: " + wmi_HD["MediaType"] + Environment.NewLine;
                richTextBox1.Text += "Removable: " + wmi_HD["Removable"] + Environment.NewLine;

            ++i;
        }
```

I have looked here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394346(v=vs.85).aspx#properties

To see if I could see if it was the boot drive and I don't see anything.

I'm getting nothing returned on anything but the SerialNumber, everything else is blank.

This is what I get on the above code:

> Name:
>
> SerialNumber:             5YZ01J34
>
> MediaType:
>
> Removable:

How do I get the serial number of the boot drive and also the information that is not showing above?

Thanks again!

Comment: On my system (which has a single internal SATA hard disk), I get NULL for all values except `SerialNumber` and `Tag`; `Tag` is `\\.\\PHYSICALDRIVE0`. There's no information in`Win32_PhysicalMedia` that tells you whether or not it's the boot disk. (And you don't boot from the physical media, anyway; you boot from the logical disk, which is in 'Win32_LogicalDisk`, but that just lists the partitions; it doesn't tell you which one was booted from either. You might want to grab the free [MagWMI](http://www.magsys.co.uk/delphi) components - the included demo lets you do WMI queries and see output.

Comment: Thank you for the input but I try to avoid any 3rd party applications. If I have problems with them, then I am at their mercy. So far, I have been able to avoid doing that.

Comment: I was suggesting using the MagWMI demo for *you* to see what's available in the results of the various queries, not to use for anything else. It's a very useful (free) utility for testing WMI stuff and viewing all the output available from them.

Comment: ah sry I misread. Ty I will check it out

Comment: Are you aware this makes a very bad way to identify a machine?  In a RAID setup some controllers will give you the ID of whatever drive happens to be available.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here you're talking about a **drive** (as it's bootable), not a **disk**. A drive is *logical* and represented by a letter (C, D....etc.), and a disk is *physical* and represented by a number (from 0 to N).
In your example you used WMI and `Win32_PhysicalMedia`, which is wrong as this class is about disks, not drives.

Here is what you want using P/Invoke:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication3
{
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
    using System.Text;

    public class Drive
    {
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool GetVolumeInformation(
            string rootPathName,
            StringBuilder volumeNameBuffer,
            int volumeNameSize,
            ref uint volumeSerialNumber,
            ref uint maximumComponentLength,
            ref uint fileSystemFlags,
            StringBuilder fileSystemNameBuffer,
            int nFileSystemNameSize);

        public string VolumeName { get; private set; }

        public string FileSystemName { get; private set; }

        public uint SerialNumber { get; private set; }

        public string DriveLetter { get; private set; }

        public static Drive GetDrive(string driveLetter)
        {
            const int VolumeNameSize = 255;
            const int FileSystemNameBufferSize = 255;
            StringBuilder volumeNameBuffer = new StringBuilder(VolumeNameSize);
            uint volumeSerialNumber = 0;
            uint maximumComponentLength = 0;
            uint fileSystemFeatures = 0;
            StringBuilder fileSystemNameBuffer = new StringBuilder(FileSystemNameBufferSize);

            if (GetVolumeInformation(
                string.Format("{0}:\\", driveLetter),
                volumeNameBuffer,
                VolumeNameSize,
                ref volumeSerialNumber,
                ref maximumComponentLength,
                ref fileSystemFeatures,
                fileSystemNameBuffer,
                FileSystemNameBufferSize))
            {
                return new Drive
                    {
                        DriveLetter = driveLetter,
                        FileSystemName = fileSystemNameBuffer.ToString(),
                        VolumeName = volumeNameBuffer.ToString(),
                        SerialNumber = volumeSerialNumber
                    };
            }

            // Something failed, returns null
            return null;
        }
    }
}


Drive drive = Drive.GetDrive("C");

Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Volumne name: {0}", drive.VolumeName));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("File system name: {0}", drive.FileSystemName));
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("SerialNumber: {0:X}", drive.SerialNumber));
```

- If you want more information about your drive, you can use [DeviceIoControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with [IOCTL_DISK_GET_DRIVE_GEOMETRY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365169%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code to get the geometry of the associated disk (bytes per cluster, sectors per track...).
- You can also get additional information (starting offset, partition number, hidden sectors...) using [IOCTL_DISK_GET_PARTITION_INFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365179%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) control code.

---

Now, the same using WMI:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDisk");

foreach (ManagementObject drive in searcher.Get())
{
    Console.WriteLine("-------");
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("VolumeName: {0}", drive["VolumeName"]));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("VolumeSerialNumber: {0}", drive["VolumeSerialNumber"]));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("MediaType: {0}", drive["MediaType"]));
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("FileSystem: {0}", drive["FileSystem"]));
}
```

Note I've used [Win32_LogicalDisk](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa394173%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) as we're talking about drives (named here *logical disks*).

Comment: Windows might use the term "drive" exclusively as being a logical something but outside of Windows a "drive" is a physical something, as in tape drive. The name "Win32_LogicalDisk" implies that even Windows does not consider a disk to always be physical. A better concept to explain is partitions that make a physical drive into multiple logical drives.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static string Mtd_GetDriveLetterWithLabel(string DriveLabel)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher DriveLabelQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher(" SELECT * FROM Win32_Volume WHERE Label = '" + DriveLabel + "' ");

    string DriveLetter = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject DriveLabels in DriveLabelQuery.Get())
    {
        DriveLetter = DriveLabels["DriveLetter"].ToString();
    }
    return DriveLetter;
}




public static int Mtd_GetDiskNumberWithLetter(string DriveLetter)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher DriveLetterGeneralQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_LogicalDiskToPartition");
    ManagementObjectCollection DriveLetterCollection = DriveLetterGeneralQuery.Get();

    string Dependent = @"\\" + Environment.MachineName + "\\root\\cimv2:Win32_LogicalDisk.DeviceID=\"" + DriveLetter + "\"";
    String DiskNumberTxt = "";
    foreach (ManagementObject DiskNumbers in DriveLetterCollection)
    {
        if ((DiskNumbers["Dependent"].ToString()) == Dependent)
        {
            DiskNumberTxt = DiskNumbers["Antecedent"].ToString();
        }
    }

    int From = DiskNumberTxt.IndexOf("Disk #") + "Disk #".Length;
    int To = DiskNumberTxt.IndexOf(",");
    String DiskNumberTrim = DiskNumberTxt.Substring(From, To - From);

    int DiskNumber = Int32.Parse(DiskNumberTrim);
    return DiskNumber;
}




public static string Mtd_GetSerialNumberWithDiskNumber(int DiskNumber)
{
    ManagementObjectSearcher SerialNumberQuery = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM Win32_PhysicalMedia");
    ManagementObjectCollection SerialNumberCollection = SerialNumberQuery.Get();

    string Tag = @"\\.\PHYSICALDRIVE" + DiskNumber;
    String SerialNumberTxt = "";

    foreach (ManagementObject SerialNumbers in SerialNumberCollection)
    {
        if ((SerialNumbers["Tag"].ToString()) == Tag)
        {
            SerialNumberTxt = SerialNumbers["SerialNumber"].ToString();
        }
    }
    return SerialNumberTxt;
}



string DriveLabel = "DATA";
 
string DriveLetter = Mtd_GetDriveLetterWithLabel(DriveLabel);
            Console.WriteLine(DriveLetter);
                       
int DiskNumber = Mtd_GetDiskNumberWithLetter(DriveLetter);
Console.WriteLine(DiskNumber);

string DiskSerialNumber = Mtd_GetSerialNumberWithDiskNumber(DiskNumber);
Console.WriteLine(DiskSerialNumber);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).