# Get files from specified digital camera

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, file-io, usb

I would like to copy then delete the images from my digital cameras.
There are 3 digital camera to connected to the pc via USB.

The pc sees these devices and add them as drives. I could copy the images from the drive, just I have to know whe do I copy the images from. Drive of the camera can change. It depends on which camera will be read and added earlier to the pc.

How should I indentify the cameras and copy the files from them.

Comment: 1. Why not copy the whole drive?
2. You could use [`DriveInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.driveinfo.getdrives.aspx) and switches.
3. Parse the directory structure, etc...
4. Use something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9038697/get-serial-number-of-boot-drive-and-other-info) to get the serial number.

Comment: 1. I could copy, but I have to also indentify the camera. 
2. I have not used yet, it was the question, what should I.
3. I do not really understand, but I hope you do not think to the const string.
4. I am gonna check it

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with them in terms of them being removable disks is relatively easy, firstly finding the removable disks using `DriveInfo`

```
// Find removable disks
var drives = DriveInfo.GetDrives().Where(x => x.DriveType == DriveType.Removable && x.IsReady);

List<FileInfo[]> pictureHandles = new List<FileInfo[]>();

// Find all files of a certain type on each drive
foreach(var drive in drives)
{
    pictureHandles.Add(
                new DirectoryInfo(drive.Name)
                .GetFiles("*.jpg",SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                .ToArray());
}

// Do stuff with pictureHandles and identify
// which drive is which camera using System.Management
```

Identifying the cameras themselves will be more complicated. Only you will know exactly how to identify them, but I would suggest using `WMI` via `System.Management`. [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7365/Retrieving-Hardware-Information-in-C)'s an article demonstrating the `ManagementObjectSearcher` class, where you could look for the digital cameras on USB via certain properties, such as `GUID`, `Name`, etc. If I remember correctly, you would initialise it like so:

```
var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("SELECT * FROM WIN32_USB");
```

And then iterate through,

```
foreach(var device in searcher.Get())
```

and check the properties:

```
if(device["Name"].ToString().Equals("My Digital Camera"))
```

Finally, when you have done whatever you wanted to do to the files, you can delete them like so:

```
foreach(FileInfo[] files in pictureHandles)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
        try 
        { 
            File.Delete(files[i].FullName); 
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            // Failed to delete
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I would have 2 questions.
1. At the first example I got an exception, the device is not ready. This device is an Nikon D3000 camera.
2. How can I get the files after that I could indintify and I got the ManagementObject?

Comment: First one is solved by adding `x.IsReady` to the conditions in the LINQ (that was my bad, updated to show this). You would do the management object searching right after getting the picture handles. You can then access each file using the same kind of `foreach` that I used to delete the files.

Comment: I am afraid my "remove able device (nikon d3200 camera)" will never be ready to use. Can I do anything for it?

I try to use an api http://dotnet.dzone.com/articles/windows-portable-devices but I got an com in use exception.